# android - firebase database reading nested list error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read the following data structure

```
   {
  "posts" : {
    "-KroPYVVmlkRXjiX1FhD" : {
      "appliedUsers" : {
        "flaged" : false,
        "latitude" : 0,
        "longitude" : 0,
        "noFlags" : 0,
        "noPosts" : 0,
        "rating" : 0
      },
      "salary" : "5454564",
      "title" : "زسروس",
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "########" : {
      "birthDate" : "8-18-1995",
      "flaged" : false,
      "image" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/11018975_10153075514031013_8079824273778693128_n.jpg?oh=7d4a511abf155a65cda6dde4bfe7b180&oe=59F52E95",
      "latitude" : 30.784419,
      "longitude" : 30.987274,
      "name" : "Aya Mohamed Hamed",
      "noFlags" : 0,
      "noPosts" : 0,
      "rating" : 0,
      "uid" : "########",
      "userPhone" : "01007211319"
    }
  }
}
```

using the following POJO

```
public class Job {

public Map<String, User> appliedUsers = new HashMap<>();
private String title;
private String salary;
// empty public constructor
// another constructor
// public getters and setters per each property
```

and the User POJO class

```
public class User  {

    private String uid;
    private String image;
    private String name;
    private String birthDate;
    private String userPhone;
    private long rating;
    private int noPosts;
    private int noFlags;
    private String address;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;
    private boolean isFlaged;
// empty public constructor
// another constructor
// public getters and setters per each property}
```

My Read Jobs function is:

```
 public static void getAllJobs(JobsDataChangeListener jobsDataChangeListener) {
        postsDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");
        postsDBRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                ArrayList<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
                Logging.log(""+dataSnapshot.getValue());
                Job job = dataSnapshot.getValue(Job.class);
                jobs.add(job);
                jobsDataChangeListener.onJobsDataChange(jobs, 1);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i(getClass().getName().toString(), ": " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

The function was retrieving posts fine until I inserted the applied users Map to the Pojo object, each time I try to read the jobs/posts, I get the following issue

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object
>   of type java.lang.Long to type com.jobease.www.jobease.models.User

Comment: find my answer.

Comment: Answer below. If that's not it, share the code for `User` too. And for this and future questions: share the JSON as text, instead of a screenshot. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data under `appliedUsers` does not match your definition in code.

```
appliedUsers
  flaged: false
  latitude: 0
```

In your code you're mapping this to:

```
public Map<String, User> appliedUsers = new HashMap<>();
```

You didn't share the definition of `User`, but it seems unlikely that it's a type that allows both a `boolean` (for `flaged`) and a number (for `latitude`).

When you're trying to read the job, the client throws an error because it can't convert `0` to a `User` object.

**Update**

If what you have under `appliedUsers` is a single user, your definition should be:

```
public class Job {
    public User appliedUsers;
    private String title;
    private String salary;
    ...
```

Comment: then am just not inserting a User object in the first Place

Comment: Are you saying that the `flaged`, `latitude` and such are from a single user? If so, you shouldn't be using a map of users in your code. See the update to my answer.

Comment: No, It is suppossed to be multible users, any one can apply to a single job that's why I used a Map

Comment: Thanks Frank you helped me understand the issue <3

Comment: But the JSON structure you're trying to read seems to only have a single user under `appliedUsers`. That's the reason for the error message: the JSON doesn't match the code. You'll either need to modify the code to handle a single user (as I've shown), or the JSON to contain multiple users.

Comment: It wasn't the answer to my issue but you pointed out that I was reading a wrong data structure than what I was expecting, voted up. Thanq

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("posts")
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        Job job = dataSnapshot.getValue(Job.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Excuse me, where's the difference?!

Comment: .getReference().child("posts") this is the difference

Comment: you try or not?

Comment: although there's no difference between the two methods, I did tried it and got the same results :), thanks for trying